# How to style a custom component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props

A component has been created that I can not edit:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import FlexRow from '../../layouts/FlexRow'

const RowContainer = styled('div')<TableRowProps>(
  ({theme, padding, active, hoverActive=true}): any => ({
    position: 'relative',
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.concrete}`,
    borderLeft: active ? `4px solid ${theme.primaryDark}` : 'none',
    boxShadow: active ? `inset 16px 0px 0px 0px ${theme.alabaster}, inset 0px 2px 4px -2px rgba(44, 51, 55, 0.16)` : 'none',
    backgroundColor: active ? `${theme.alabaster}` : 'none',
    padding: padding ?? `20px 16px 20px ${active ? '12px' : '16px'}`,
    '&:hover': hoverActive ? {
      borderLeft: `4px solid ${theme.schist}`,
      paddingLeft: '12px',
      backgroundColor: `${theme.alabaster}`,
      boxShadow: `inset 16px 0px 0px 0px ${theme.alabaster}, inset 0px 2px 4px -2px rgba(44, 51, 55, 0.16)`
    } : {}
  })
)

type TableRowProps = {
  theme?: any
  padding?: string
  active?: boolean,
  hoverActive?: boolean
}

export const Row = (props) => <RowContainer padding={props.padding} active={props.active} hoverActive={props.hoverActive} ><FlexRow {...props} /></RowContainer>
```

I'm using this component with a custom Table component like this:

```
<Table.Row {...flexProps} className="TableRow">
```

I'm wanting to remove the padding from Row and have tried:

```
<Table.Row style={{ padding: 0 }}>...</Table.Row>
```

How can I access it's props and make changes to the component?

Comment: Can't you simply use `<Table.Row padding="0">`? The component already forwards `props.padding`

Comment: @Phil no this doesn't work

Comment: So what did it do instead?

Comment: @Phil it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I find that hard to believe given it literally has `padding: padding ?? ...`

Comment: hence the question @Phil it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can clearly see in the CodeSandbox linked below that it does in fact work

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `Row` component forwards any `padding` prop to the `RowContainer` where it uses it for the padding style (falling back to `20px 16px 20px ${active ? '12px' : '16px'}`), you can simply set `padding="0"` when you use it

```jsx
<Table.Row padding="0">...</Table.Row>
```

[image: Edit hardcore-cray-004gfo]